# Sorry Something Went Wrong

Tags: 2013, error, troubleshooting

I have tried everything to get my Development environment up and running but I'm still seeing this error on all Site Collection AND Central Admin! It only has one App server and the DB server so here is what I tried so far

- Rebooted servers
- restarted Services
- Restarted App Pools
- ?contents=1
- ULS logs
- Event Viewers - nothing

The thing is, I can deploy solutions through Visual Studio no problem and connect through SharePoint designer, but not through the browser. Any ideas on what to check?

[image]

Comment: Check the log files? Use the co relation id to find the exact issue.

Comment: The Unexpected error may be a clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the error by my seems that it is due to a custom component since it is looking for a MySQL instance. Correct?

I don't know how you configured the connection to your MySQL server from SharePoint but there are two ptions:
 - has the current user access to that location using the given address/account
 - has the application pool account, of that web application, access to that location using the given address/account

Comment: I did install MySQL workbench which may have cause the issue! I'll try uninstalling that

Comment: ...And that was the issue. First time integrating MYSQL with SP and apparently you can't install any client tools on a SP server

Answer (score 1):

From the error logs

> UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.

To solve this check

1. If the site storage quota is not exceeded
2. SQL drive has enough free space
3. Check you mysite webapplication

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

This shows some issues with the SQL itself. Check connecting to the SQL using client tools.

Comment: Not sure how to check the quota if Central Admin isn't working. SQL has lots of space. MySites is down also.
I can connect to the DB through Visual Studio and SQL Server Mgmt Studio